# DropWizard UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory injection

Tags: guice, dropwizard, unit-of-work

I am following the below link to add UnitOfWork on non resource methods.

[Create @UnitOfWork-aware proxies of existing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261787/create-unitofwork-aware-proxies-of-existing-objects/38267726#38267726)

The problem is

```
    @Inject UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory proxyFactory
```

calls the following method during application startup in Module

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory provideUnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(HibernateBundle<AlexandriaConfiguration> hibernateBundle) {
        return new UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory(hibernateBundle);}
```

UnitOfWorkAwareProxyFactory calls hibernateBundle.getSessionFactory which is null at that time, which throws an exception.

Need a way to remove UnitOfWork from resource.
I am using guice for dependency injection.